# No response from elasticsearch thru sense and browser

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, configuration

I've installed ElasticSearch 5.3 on my Windows 10 machine recently and after following the installation process, ES does not respond when I access **http://localhost:9200** and from Chrome's **Sense**.

However, when I use `curl 'http://localhost:9200'` on the command line, it sends this:

```
{
  "name" : "test",
  "cluster_name" : "my-application",
  "cluster_uuid" : "9-wvh6UXTHSKmkdpblqyyA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.3.0",
    "build_hash" : "3adb13b",
    "build_date" : "2017-03-23T03:31:50.652Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.4.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

which indicates that the ES is running/configured correctly(?).

I also configured `network.host:` to `0.0.0.0`/`127.0.0.1`/`::` of *elasticsearch.yml* still no effect.

Here is the latest log info:

```
[2017-04-07T18:21:06,481][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [test] initializing ...
[2017-04-07T18:21:06,633][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [test] using [1] data paths, mounts [[OSDisk (C:)]], net usable_space [129.2gb], net total_space [232.3gb], spins? [unknown], types [NTFS]
[2017-04-07T18:21:06,634][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [test] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2017-04-07T18:21:06,681][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [test] node name [test], node ID [Ab5g3zN0S7qNOuP_asF-iQ]
[2017-04-07T18:21:06,682][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [test] version[5.3.0], pid[312], build[3adb13b/2017-03-23T03:31:50.652Z], OS[Windows 10/10.0/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_121/25.121-b13]
[2017-04-07T18:21:08,288][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2017-04-07T18:21:08,289][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2017-04-07T18:21:08,291][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2017-04-07T18:21:08,291][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [lang-groovy]
[2017-04-07T18:21:08,292][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2017-04-07T18:21:08,294][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2017-04-07T18:21:08,295][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [percolator]
[2017-04-07T18:21:08,296][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [reindex]
[2017-04-07T18:21:08,296][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [transport-netty3]
[2017-04-07T18:21:08,298][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2017-04-07T18:21:08,299][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded plugin [ltr-query]
[2017-04-07T18:21:11,330][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [test] initialized
[2017-04-07T18:21:11,330][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [test] starting ...
[2017-04-07T18:21:11,612][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [test] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}, {[::1]:9300}
[2017-04-07T18:21:14,657][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [test] new_master {test}{Ab5g3zN0S7qNOuP_asF-iQ}{XYHTUZ8AQN6kYrEPLChFNg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
[2017-04-07T18:21:14,826][INFO ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport] [test] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9200}, {[::1]:9200}
[2017-04-07T18:21:14,826][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [test] started
[2017-04-07T18:21:14,982][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [test] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
[2017-04-07T18:21:15,510][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [test] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[tmdb][0]] ...]).
```

Comment: Did you check Elasticsearch logs? Can you post those log info here if possible?

Comment: @avr - added the latest log info.

Comment: Logs look good. Did you try accessing ES from Kibana(Dev_Tools)?

Comment: @avr - After reading the Network Settings Doc., I tried to ran it with the argument `-E network.host=_local_`, and it worked. I posted my answer below.
Thanks btw!

Comment: You don't need to explicitly set `network.host` to `_local_` as it already default value for it. I'm still wondering why it didn't work earlier? btw what value did you set earlier for `network.host`?

Comment: It was `192.168.0.1` then I changed it to `0.0.0.0` then to `non_loopback` and finally to `_local_`. I also wondered why it didn't work at `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: That's strange! However you can comment it(`network.host`) as you are using default `_local_` setting only.

Comment: @avr - Thank you! That's more I like it. I'll change my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Referring from [Network Settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html) Documentation, I tried to run it using this script: `elasticsearch.bat -E network.host=_local_`, and it worked!

I also changed the configuration file(*./config/elasticsearch.yml*). Just uncomment the line and change it to `network.host: _local_`. After that, I simply ran *elasticsearch.bat* directly.

**OR**

to put it simply just comment the `network.host` line.